# Загрузка .php если есть .txt в диске C:/

Tags: php, безопасность

На сервере есть страницы, доступна по ссылке http://mysite.ru/admin.php. Но хочу, чтоб данная страница открывалась только с моего компьютера. Можно ли сделать так, чтоб при наличии файла в C:/dostup.txt данная страница (admin.php) отрывалась, а в случает отсутствия в диске "С" файла dostup.txt файл admin.php не работал что ли?

Кто-нибудь делал такое? Что читать? Подскажите, буду рад любой помощи.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можете сделать так, чтобы логин осуществлялся только при закачке правильного файла (наличии правильной куки, задаваемой вручную или как-то еще). А прочитать что-либо с диска пользователя без его согласия (закачки файла) не получится.

Answer (score 1):

Если у вас статический ip адресс - просто проверяйте IP, если IP не ваш делайте 404, все гениальное просто, если же нет, то никак :)

Answer (score 0):

Настрой аутентификацию пользователей на сервере. создай .htpasswd с логином-паролем, и .htaccess в котором пропиши полный путь к файлу с паролем. А доступ к файлу на локальном диске скрипт в общем случае не получит по соображениям безопасности

Answer (score 0):

Нет! php скрипт работает на сервере и может открывать только файлы с сервака. Как вариант, можно в ручную передавать файл, зашифрованный, а там скрипту написать алгоритм расшифровки. Еще проще использовать SSL. Или привязать к IP.